# Track if the user is absent using 2 for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

I'm creating an angularjs **attendance-system** and I'm having trouble counting the absent of an employee for example. I tried using two for loops for this problem but its still giving me too many absent values.

**Example**

**days.length** has a value of 30 from `11-1-17 - 11-30-17`

```
getDaysInMonth(10, 2017);

function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {

  var date = new Date(year, month, 1);


  console.log('month', month, 'date.getMonth()', date.getMonth());

  while (date.getMonth() === month) {
    days.push(moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }

  return days;

}
```

**objArray** has 4 value `11-27-2017, 11-28-2017, 11-29-2017, 11-30-2017`

**controller (for loop)**

```
for (var y = 0; y < days.length; y++) {
    for (var z = 0; z < objArray.length; z++) {
      if (days[y] === moment(objArray[z].day).format('MM-DD-YYYY')) {
        console.log('exist', days[y]);
      } else {
        console.log('absent'); // giving me a lot of value
      }
    }
  }
```

### Edit

**objArray values**

```
objArray: [
  {
    day: "2017-11-26"
  },
  {
    day: "2017-11-27"
  },
  {
    day: "2017-11-28"
  }
]
```

Comment: is `objArray` an array of strings? And what does `objArray` represents (present days or absent days)?

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes.

Comment: @gurvinder372 i added the `objArray` values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `objArray` is already an array of Strings, then you can loose the inner-loop

```
for (var y = 0; y < days.length; y++) {
      if ( objArray.indexOf(days[y]) != -1 ) { //use index of instead of comparing individual values
        console.log('exist', days[y]);
      } else {
        console.log('absent'); 
      }
 }
```

Or more precisely

```
days.forEach(function(day) {
  console.log(day, (objArray.indexOf(day) != -1) ? "exist " + day : "absent");
})
```

**Edit**

Convert `objArray` to string array first before comparison

```
objArray = objArray.map( function(item){
   item = item.day.split("-");
   return item[1] + "-" + item[2] + "-" + item[0].slice(-2)
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var days = ["11-1-17", "11-2-17", "11-3-17", "11-4-17", "11-5-17", "11-6-17", "11-7-17", "11-8-17", "11-9-17", "11-10-17", "11-11-17", "11-12-17", "11-13-17", "11-14-17", "11-15-17", "11-16-17", "11-17-17", "11-18-17", "11-19-17", "11-20-17", "11-21-17", "11-22-17", "11-23-17", "11-24-17", "11-25-17", "11-26-17", "11-27-17", "11-28-17", "11-29-17", "11-30-17" ];

var objArray = [ { day: "2017-11-26" }, { day: "2017-11-27" }, { day: "2017-11-28" } ];

objArray = objArray.map( function(item){
   item = item.day.split("-");
   return item[1] + "-" + item[2] + "-" + item[0].slice(-2)
})

days.forEach(function(day) {
  console.log(day, (objArray.indexOf(day) != -1) ? "exist " + day : "absent");
})
```

Comment: Tried you answer but its just giving me all `absent` value.

Comment: @Priz Can you share a sample `objArray` along with `days`? Is there any trimming required?

Comment: @Priz I have added a demo as well.

Comment: my mistake i think my `arrayObj` value is a bunch of objects

Comment: @Priz Can you share the exact representation of this object?

Comment: @Priz Even better, please create a working snippet using `<>` in your question itself.

Comment: in your **demo** why is the value all exist ? when they don't match with `days`

Comment: @Priz Because I was comparing 17 with 2017, fixed now - please check

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the double loop that is printing too many values.
Also, if you have string values like "11-30-2017" in your objArray, then there is a problem here

**moment(objArray[z].day)** will be equalent to **moment(undefined)**
Hence, you will always get a moment object that has only current date.

A small change that can help correct your print statement is to use flags

```
var exist;
for( outer loop condition  )
{
   exist=false;
  for( inner loop condition  ){
  if( condition ){
     exist=true;
     break;
   }
 }
  //Check flag and print absent/exists status
}
```